# How to use jQuery within PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using a php tree browser that I got from http://www.lateralcode.com/directory-trees-with-php-and-jquery/

```
<?php
 $path = ".";

 function createDir($path = '/')
 { 
  if ($handle = opendir($path)) 
  {
   echo "<ul>";

   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
   {
    if (is_dir($path.$file) && $file != '.' && $file !='..')
     printSubDir($file, $path, $queue);
    else if ($file != '.' && $file !='..')
     $queue[] = $file;
   }

   printQueue($queue, $path);
   echo "</ul>";
  }
 }

 function printQueue($queue, $path)
 {
  foreach ($queue as $file) 
  {
   printFile($file, $path);
  } 
 }

 function printFile($file, $path)
 { 
  echo "<li><a style=\"cursor:pointer\" ".
       "onClick=\"parent.right.document.getElementById('file_path').value='".
       "$file_path'\">$file_path</a></li>";
 }

 function printSubDir($dir, $path)
 {
  echo "<li><span class=\"toggle\">$dir</span>";
  createDir($path.$dir."/");

 ?>

 **<script language="javascript">
   $(document).click(function(e) { 
   if (e.button == 0) {
    // was the left button
    alert('clicked'); 
   }
  });
  </script>**

 <?php 
  echo "</li>";
```

However, I want to detect a right-click that is pressed inbetween, so that I can trigger an event. However, I can't seem to get the jquery code to work within my PHP. The reason being, that I don't get an alert popup when I execute the code ... Ideally, I want to have this included within my php code, since I need to use my php `variable $file_path`

Comment: It appears you don't understand how PHP works and how JavaScript works -- JavaScript runs on the browser while PHP runs on the server. Maybe you should go read a tutorial on either one or both of them?

Answer (score 2):

PHP can only process code and send output to the browser. jQuery runs strictly in the browser and will either be executed when the DOM loads it (ie, when PHP sends it and the browser receives/processes it) or when the document has finished loading (usually preferable).  To do the latter use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).click(function(e) { 
   if (e.button == 0) {
    // was the left button
    alert('clicked'); 
   }
  });
});
```

I'm making the assumption your code is correct because it isn't extremely clear what you're trying to do.  But that might shore up some of your problems.

Comment: Hi Clif ... What I'm trying to do is that when someone "right" clicks on a printer directory tree, I want to perform a certain function. In the code, I was using "left" click ... just to test if that works first at least. So basically, when the directory tree is printed, the left click helps go down deeper into the directory. I want to reserve "right" click to do something else. I posted another question on SO, and I was recommended to use jQuery to figure out which mouse key was pressed. However, I am having difficulty integrating that into my existing php code ..

Comment: You're attaching your click event to the document. This doesn't make sense. You'll need to target whatever HTML element you want to be clickable.  Like one of the commenters suggested, you really need to go through a tutorial and  get the basics down. At a minimum, post a link to the full working tree and people can give advice on how to use jQuery to make it work like you want.

Comment: Here's a link to the tree: http://demo.lateralcode.com/directory-tree/. I will try out a few tutorials ... I'm relatively new to jQuery and am not familiar with its syntax at all. But I know I can embed javascript in PHP by enclosing it with an echo""; , so I thought I could do the same ... But you guys are right, I need to be looking at tutorials and figuring this out on my own. I will attempt to do this ...